# Node-request - How to determine if an error occurred during the request?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to leverage the [node-request module](https://github.com/voxpelli/node-request), but the documentation isn't that great. If I make a request to a valid resource and pipe it to a Writable Stream, everything works fine. However, if I make a request to an invalid object, the Writable Stream is still created. Example, take the following snippet:

```
var x = request("http://localhost:3000/foo.jpg");
var st = fs.createWriteStream("foo.jpg");
x.pipe(st);
```

If the foo.jpg resource exists on the server, the data is piped to the stream, and it creates the file fine on the server. However, if foo.jpg **does not** exist on the server, a blank container file is still created. There appears to be no error event or anything that can be leveraged to determine if the request returned a 404. I've tried something like the following:

```
var x = request("http://localhost:3000/foo.jpg", function(err, response, body) {
    if(response.statusCode === 200) {
        // Success
        var st = fs.createWriteStream("foo.jpg");
        x.pipe(st);
    }
});
```

And also:

```
request("http://localhost:3000/foo.jpg", function(err, response, body) {
    if(response.statusCode === 200) {
        // Success
        var x = response.request;
        var st = fs.createWriteStream("foo.jpg");
        x.pipe(st);
    }
});
```

To no avail. The idea is pretty simple; I just want to copy a file identified by the URL to the local server. If the request is invalid (404, etc), don't pipe the file; if the request is valid, pipe the file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Wait, I'm not exactly sure what you want to accomplish here.  What do you want copied and when?

Comment: For the love of god use [`request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request) instead of node-request.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I wrote a request :)

you might want to try this

```
var r = request(url)
r.on('response', function (resp) {
   resp.headers 
   resp.statusCode
   r.pipe(new WritableStream())
})
```

Comment: and how would you retry the request if status code was 503 and you wanted to pipe the response to your server's response?

Comment: found a way. check my answer.

Comment: I am using request. I wonder how this get a callback after the file is all downloaded and saved to the stream? I need to do something when the file is downloaded. @mikeal

Answer (score 22):

The way I ended up succeeding with new Streams in node:

```
function doQuery(){
    var r = request(url)
    r.pause()
    r.on('response', function (resp) {
       if(resp.statusCode === 200){
           r.pipe(new WritableStream()) //pipe to where you want it to go
           r.resume()
       }else{  }
    })
}
```

This is really flexible - if you want to retry, you can call the function recursively with `setTimeout`

```
function doQuery(){
    var r = request(url)
    r.pause()
    r.on('response', function (resp) {
       if(resp.statusCode === 200){
           r.pipe(new WritableStream()) //pipe to where you want it to go
           r.resume()
       }else{ 
           setTimeout(doQuery,1000)
       }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify why pausing and resuming the stream is necessary compared to @mikeal's answer?

Comment: I think it's because you want to pause the stream (not get any data) until you know for sure, resource on that server exits. When you are sure it exists, pipe that stream wherever you want and resume (in fact start) downloading/streaming that resource.

Comment: I wrote that comment once, no idea what happened to it... Streams start flowing too early and under load, you'll get a file that doesn't have first few bytes.

Answer (score 5):

@Mikeal solution looks great, but may have some problem with the piping (first few bytes can be missed).
Hee is an updated code:

```
var r = request(url)
r.pipe(new WritableStream());
r.on('response', function (resp) {
   resp.headers 
   resp.statusCode
   // Handle error case and remove your writablestream if need be.
})
```

Comment: Dude You are awesome! closing the writableStream worked. Not doing so crash exits the process. Cheers !

Comment: But what if the page returns both 404 and a response body? Delete the file after it's been written?

Answer (score -5):

Why not use the http module directly.[http.request](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.2/api/http.html#http.request)

It has an 'error' event which you can use to catch the error.

Comment: Because `http.request` is a low level API compared to `request`. It's a pain to use

Comment: I suppose the native http.request may be the way to go.